# grails named query returns incorrect data

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a simple query in a domain class  ..

```
   inventoryItems { String partNumber, String serialReference, Vendor vendor ->

        def c = InventoryMaster.createCriteria()

        def results = c.list {

            if(partNumber) {
                println "part  .. ${partNumber} ..."
                part {
                    eq 'partNumber', partNumber
                }
            }

            if(vendor) {
                println "vendor  .. ${vendor} ... "
               part {
                    eq 'vendor', vendor
                }
            }

            if(serialReference) {
                println "serial reference .. ${serialReference}"
                eq 'serialReference', serialReference
            }

        }

        results

    }
```

I call this providing 2 params initially (serialReference and vendor) and it correctly returns 2 items .. I refine it by adding a third param (partNumber) and it **incorrectly**  returns 2 items instead of the 1 expected .. I have sql logging switched on , copied the generated stmt and ran it tru the dbconsole where it **correctly** returned the 1 item expected .. I have **no** caching switched on that I can see and am running grails 2.3.7 .. Can anyone suggest what i'm doing wrong or what is causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you calling `InventoryMaster.createCriteria()` from inside the named query?

Comment: Your correct , i am stupid .. Sorry, shouldn't work so late

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simplify the query a bit with something like this:

```
inventoryItems { String partNumber, String serialReference, Vendor vendor ->

    part {
        if(partNumber) {
            println "part  .. ${partNumber} ..."
            eq 'partNumber', partNumber
        }
        if(vendor) {
            println "vendor  .. ${vendor} ... "
            eq 'vendor', vendor
        }
    }


    if(serialReference) {
        println "serial reference .. ${serialReference}"
        eq 'serialReference', serialReference
    }
}
```